# Time complexity of Javascript ES6 backtick operator

Tags: javascript

```
var1 = "string1"
var2 = "string2"
...
varn = "stringn"

var str = `${var1}${var2}${var3}${var4}...${varn}`;
```

1.What is the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of getting `str` in above expression, given `vari` is an `string`?

2.How fast is it in comparison with concatenating strings using `for` loop?

Edit1: Added wiki link

Edit2: Another example as said by  @PatrickRoberts. It is my actual use case as well:

I am using `node` and I need to respond to client with an `XML` payload. They have already given me the format of `XML` and respective `XSD`s. These are big and nested  `XML`s. I have data (in `JSON`) which I will "fill" in `XML` template (as string) using backtick operator. I want to avoid blocking `node` thread as much as I can.

As a dummy example:

```
let response = 
`<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>${data.title}</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>${data.artist}</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>${data.country}</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>${data.company}</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>${data.price}</PRICE>
        <YEAR>${data.year}</YEAR>
    </CD>
<CATALOG>
`
```

Comment: Didn't get your first question about time complexity of getting str in above expression, given vari is an string? Do you want to check whether str is string or not?

Comment: @YatendrasinhJoddha ofc its a string. But I am interested in how much [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) it takes to evaluate.

Comment: performance can be measured, give it a try jsperf or jsben.ch

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks. will give it a try

Comment: Question, why would you append so many strings with this method that time complexity would even be a relevant factor to consider? At that point you should be collecting your string values in an array and calling `.join('')` on it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am using nodejs and I need to respond to client with an XML payload. I have data (in JSON) which I will "fill" in XML template (as string) using backtick operator.  I want to avoid blocking nodejs thread as much as I can. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense, and hardcoding the values that go into your payload is a superfluous optimization. If you're having trouble reducing the amount of time it takes to form a response, use a debugger to profile where most of your code is spending its time, but if you don't know how much time it's taking or it's not a problem, don't optimize. This makes your implementation brittle and usually buggy, as the famous quote goes "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am surprised you are calling it hardcoding. But I would be glad to know any other way to do this more efficiently and conveniently.

Comment: You'd need to give a less trivial example than joining a bunch of strings. I already gave you a more convenient way of concatenating N number of strings, as that's all that was provided in the question.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have edited the question.If I think from an outsiders perspective, it might seem like hardcoding. It is. However, in my use caase these XML definitions/formats will never change. And if they do, I think this is still the most convenient solution.   So this solution makes sense. I am in developing phase now, but I will sure look for more optimization going further. Do you have any better solution in mind?

Answer (score 0):

First, a (hopefully) compelling argument to defend my side-stepping your intention here.

<sub>`<rant>`</sub>

The question you really need to ask yourself is do you really prefer efficiency so much that re-usability means absolutely nothing to you? Efficiency is usually A Good Thing™, but keep in mind that only goes as far as maintaining [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) code. The concept is self-explanatory: If you don't repeat yourself, you do less unnecessary operations, and as an added benefit, your code is more maintainable.

And unless you're writing a server you expect to respond with megabytes of XML to hundreds of requests per second, the level of efficiency where you start to concern yourself with the performance of string concatenation will never come into play, so until that's the case, you should be thinking about more important things like how to make your code re-usable so you don't end up re-implementing the same thing over and over with slightly different tweaks each time to fit your specific use-case, as what seems to be your current situation.

<sup>`</rant>`</sup>

Now to answer your question. As I have no idea what your "real" XML looks like, I will address your example with a non-hardcoded solution that will not require the implementation to change much, even if the API response JSON does.

```js
// assuming you have valid object referenced by `data`
const data = {
  title: 'Code Monkey',
  artist: 'SKG',
  country: 'US',
  company: 'Stack Overflow',
  price: '12.98',
  year: 2006
};

function toXML ([key, value]) {
  const tag = key.toUpperCase();
  return `<${tag}>${value}</${tag}>`;
}

const response = `<CATALOG><CD>
${Object.entries(data).map(toXML).join('\n')}
</CD></CATALOG>`;

console.log(response);
```

Seeing how neither whitespace nor order matter in an XML response, this approach is a *lot* more re-usable than hard-coding every single property from your JSON to your XML.

Expanding this approach, you could write a method that recursively walks arrays and objects until it reaches primitive values, serializing each hierarchy into XML tags based on their respective keys, but this assumes that your JSON schema matches your XML schema. Modifying your example a bit, that might look something like this:

```js
// assuming you have valid object referenced by `data`
const data = {
  catalog: [{
    cd: {
      title: 'Code Monkey',
      artist: 'SKG',
      country: 'US',
      company: 'Stack Overflow',
      price: '12.98',
      year: 2006
    }
  }, {
    cd: {
      title: 'Mandelbrot Set',
      artist: 'SKG',
      country: 'US',
      company: 'Stack Overflow',
      price: '9.98',
      year: 2004
    }
  }]
};

const XML = {
  stringify (value) {
    switch (typeof value) {
    case 'object':
      return (Array.isArray(value)
        ? value.map(XML.stringify)
        : Object.entries(value).map(entryToXML)
      ).join('');
    default:
      return String(value);
    }
  }
};

function entryToXML ([key, value]) {
  const tag = key.toUpperCase();
  return `<${tag}>${XML.stringify(value)}</${tag}>`;
}

const response = XML.stringify(data);

console.log(response);
```